# When do I have to explicitly open a SqlConnection?

Tags: c#, sqlconnection

I wrote the following code (trimmed for the sake of brevity):

```
using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection("Server=test;Database=test;User=test;Password=test"))
using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter())
using (DataSet ds = new DataSet())
{
    string groupsQuery = @"SELECT GroupName FROM tblGroups ORDER BY GroupName";

    da.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand(groupsQuery, cn);
    da.Fill(ds);

    foreach (System.Data.DataRow row in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
    {
        string group = row["GroupName"].ToString();
        this.GroupList.Add(group);
    }
}
```

I forgot to call `cn.Open()`, but, much to my surprise, the code ran just fine. I suspected SqlDataAdapter was doing some magic, so I went and found [the source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Data/data/System/Data/SqlClient/SqlDataAdapter.cs).

SqlDataAdapter inherits the [Fill](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Data/data/System/Data/Common/DbDataAdapter.cs#1ad77dd66ffc3149#references) method from [DbDataAdapter](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Data/data/System/Data/Common/DbDataAdapter.cs).

**Fill** calls [FillInternal](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Data/data/System/Data/Common/DbDataAdapter.cs#76ee69e4b70c4d1f#references), which wraps its logic in a block like so:

```
try {
    QuietOpen(activeConnection, out originalState);

    //... do the fill ...
}
finally {
    QuietClose(activeConnection, originalState);
}
```

`QuietOpen` and `QuietClose` are pretty simple:

```
static private void QuietClose(IDbConnection connection, ConnectionState originalState) {
    // close the connection if:
    // * it was closed on first use and adapter has opened it, AND
    // * provider's implementation did not ask to keep this connection open
    if ((null != connection) && (ConnectionState.Closed == originalState)) {
        // we don't have to check the current connection state because
        // it is supposed to be safe to call Close multiple times
        connection.Close();
    }
}

// QuietOpen needs to appear in the try {} finally { QuietClose } block
// otherwise a possibility exists that an exception may be thrown, i.e. ThreadAbortException
// where we would Open the connection and not close it
static private void QuietOpen(IDbConnection connection, out ConnectionState originalState) {
    Debug.Assert(null != connection, "QuietOpen: null connection");
    originalState = connection.State;
    if (ConnectionState.Closed == originalState) {
        connection.Open();
    }
}
```

I'm curious, when else am I calling `Open` on a SqlConnection that I don't *need* to? Should I always do it explicitly, or let .NET "quietly" do its thing?

Also, any reference to more details about why SqlDataAdapter does this would be great.

Comment: While the DataAdapters work like that, the DataReaders won't.

Answer (score 2):

From [this page on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bh8kx08z(v=vs.110).aspx):

> The Fill method implicitly opens the **Connection** that the **DataAdapter**
>   is using if it finds that the connection is not already open. If **Fill**
>   opened the connection, it also closes the connection when **Fill** is
>   finished.

Comment: But if you open the connection Fill will not close it? You are responsible for closing it if you opened it?

Comment: @PaulZahra That is correct; if you opened it yourself, `Fill()` will not close it.